# How can I encapsulate a call to XMLHttp Request inside a $q promise?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code in an AngularJS ui-router resolve section.

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "/Scripts/Pages/Home.js", false);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("X-Custom-Header", "My Values");
xmlhttp.send();
var m = document.createElement('script');
m.appendChild(document.createTextNode(xmlhttp.responseText));
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(m);
```

How can I encapsulate this in a $q promise that will return a success or fail if the http request worked? Also should I place all of this inside a promise or just the part that is getting data?

Comment: Possibly off topic-ish but I think you might want to look into `$http` or `Restangular`

Comment: But can I use $http to get javascript that I need to add to the DOM ?

Comment: Off course, you might want also want to look in to Scopes and binding for that. You probably want to take some angular tutorials, check out https://egghead.io/

Comment: Okay then that is probably a better alternative although I am not quite sure how to do it. The reason I would like to do all of this is that I need to send a request header.

Comment: You can do that with `$http` or `Restangular` and a lot less code to, but you will need to get comfortable with the framework first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to place `xmlhttp.send();` inside a promise. use javascript closure to handle callback and resove the defer object as follows:

```
function sendRequest($q){
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "/Scripts/Pages/Home.js", false);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("X-Custom-Header", "My Values");

var defer = $q.defer();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = (function(xmlhttp, def) {
    return function() {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
        {
           if (xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                def.resolve(xmlhttp)
            }
            else
            {
                def.reject(xmlhttp);
            }
        }

    }
})(xmlhttp, defer);
xmlhttp.send();
return defer.promise;
}
```

**EDIT**
using the function:

```
    sendRequest($q).then(function(xmlHttp){
        var m = document.createElement('script');
        m.appendChild(document.createTextNode(xmlhttp.responseText));
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(m);
        }
      ,function(xmlHttp){
       //error
    }
);
```

Comment: thanks very much for your detailed reply. I would like to put this into a function that I could call. Can you show me how I would wrap this in a function also? I assume I would just need var a = function($q) { xxx return defer.promise }. Is that correct ? One more question. Where would I include the part of the code that adds to the document?

Comment: Yes that is the only thing you need to do. I have edited my post.

Comment: Thanks very much. What about the code that I need to use to add the reply to the DOM? Where would that go inside the function?